# Mysql results return ungrouped

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table `thanks_entry` 
with columns

```
 - entryid
 - varname
 - userid
 - contenttype
 - contentid
 - dateline
 - receiveduserid
```

this table stores the data for likes/thanks given/received to user/by user
I want to get statistics for users with most likes/thanks per month

**Query:**

```
SELECT receiveduserid,COUNT(receiveduserid) AS receivedthanks 
FROM thanks_entry 
WHERE varname ='likes' AND dateline > 1420070400 
AND dateline <1422748800 
GROUP BY userid ORDER BY COUNT(receiveduserid) DESC LIMIT 20
```

This query should return results grouped by userid .. but looking in the result I find

```
- receiveduserid|receivedthanks
 - 185883|190
 - 43455|100
 - 163068|85
 - 2|66
 - 186270|49
 - 189468|34
 - 105597|22
 - 2|17
 - 186270|17
 - 163068|16
 - 117147|15
 - 186270|15
 - 186270|14
 - 186643|13
 - 2|12
 - 189170|12
 - 118500|8
 - 2|8
 - 105597|8
 - 2|7
```

As you notice here Although I `grouped by receiveduserid` .. `receiveduserid 2` is not grouped and appears multiple times in results ..
what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You say   `grouped by receiveduserid` but you write in your code  `GROUP BY userid ` is it right?

Comment: OMG! .. it is it .. I'm so sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:** *You may want following this*

```
SELECT receiveduserid,COUNT(receiveduserid) AS receivedthanks 
FROM thanks_entry 
WHERE varname ='likes' AND dateline > 1420070400 
AND dateline <1422748800 
GROUP BY receiveduserid  ORDER BY receivedthanks DESC LIMIT 20
```

And you want to group by multiple column then use `,`(comma) like `GROUP BY receiveduserid, another_column`   first column is priority is first...

Answer (score 0):

Select part of the query statement should include the fields in group by part of the query statement.

```
    SELECT userid,COUNT(receiveduserid) AS receivedthanks 
    FROM thanks_entry 
    WHERE varname ='likes' AND dateline > 1420070400 
    AND dateline <1422748800 
    GROUP BY userid ORDER BY COUNT(receiveduserid) DESC LIMIT 20
```